# Fourier Series: How do I get from $a_k(f')$ to $a_k(f)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I have:
f is $2\pi$ periodic

$a_k(f')=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f'(x)cos(kx)dx$

$b_k(f')=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f'(x)sin(kx)dx$

The hint of the example states that partial integration helps.

With that I get

$a_k(f')=\frac{1}{\pi}((f(x) cos(kx))|^{2\pi}_0-\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)(-ksin(kx)dx)$

At this point I am stuck and have no idea.

Any advice?

Comment: Partial integration is correct, but you need to substitue the first term on the bounds. Also remember that $f$ needs to be periodic in $2\pi$ for this to work.

Comment: By ,,substitute the first term'' you mean $(f(x)cos(x))|^{0}_{2\pi}$? f is $2\pi$ periodic. Will edit my question.

Comment: With the partial integration I will still have a(f'). I remember that the Fourier Series are just added serieses. And in the partial integration I am removing one integral of a series? I guess this is a part of the trick?

Comment: Is this called ,,Fourier transform of derivative''?

Comment: "*By ,,substitute the first term'' you mean (f(x)cos(x))|02π? f is 2π periodic. Will edit my question.*" - Yes, what do you get when you do that?

Comment: "*With the partial integration I will still have a(f'). I remember that the Fourier Series are just added serieses. And in the partial integration I am removing one integral of a series? I guess this is a part of the trick?*" - On the right hand side you wil still have $a(f')$ because you are trying to show an equality in the form of $a(f') = \varphi(a(f), b(f))$, where $\varphi$ is some function. In other words you want a relationship between the fourier series of $f'$ and $f$.

Comment: "*Is this called ,,Fourier transform of derivative''?*" - Not exactly. Fourier transform is a continous version of fourier series, which allows us to transform even non-periodic functions. However the idea is pretty much the same.

Comment: Why is there a a(f') in the right hand side of the partial intergration of a(f)? I still do not understand how to get from ak(f) to ak(f'). I have done the partial Integration and I end up with:

Comment: $a_k(f')=\frac{1}{\pi}((f(x) cos(kx))|^{2\pi}_0-\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)(-ksin(kx)dx)$

Comment: $a_k(f')=0-\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)(-ksin(kx)dx)$

Comment: $a_k(f')=\frac{k}{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)(sin(kx)dx)$

Comment: So how does this now justify to $a_k(f)$?

Comment: what is the definition of $b_k(f)$?

Comment: $b_{{k}}={\frac  {1}{\pi }}\int _{{-\pi }}^{{\pi }}f(t)\cdot \sin \left(kt\right){\mathrm  d}t\quad {\text{for }}k\geq 1$

Comment: With the actual equation it is still $a_k(f′)=k\frac{1}{\pi}\int^{2\pi}_0f(x)(sin(kx)dx$

Comment: $a_k(f')=k*b_k(f) \forall f$ that are $2\pi$-periodic?

Comment: yes, that's it :)

Comment: Thanks for your help sir!